# Why cant i draw a line?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw a line from the left top of my rectangle to the center? The rectangle comes up but not a line...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.strokeRect(10,10,300,175);
    ctx.moveTo(10,10);
    ctx.lineTo(140, 87);
 </script>
```

(This is inside the body tag)

Comment: missing stroke ctx.stroke();

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`ctx.stroke();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/stroke) after your `lineTo`:

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.stroke() method of the Canvas 2D API strokes the current or given path with the current stroke style using the non-zero winding rule.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(140, 87);
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
```

Answer (score 0):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo):

> The CanvasRenderingContext2D.lineTo() method of the Canvas 2D API connects the last point in the sub-path to the x, y coordinates with a straight line (**but does not actually draw it**).
>
> use the `stroke()` method to actually draw the line

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeRect(10, 10, 300, 175);
ctx.moveTo(10, 10);
ctx.lineTo(140, 87);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```